# How can I achieve this shadow effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, photoshop-effects

[image: image from a greeting card I found on internet]

I saw this image and loved the shadow effect and assumed it is made on Photoshop. It reminds me of old airbrush like in art deco posters. It is not even and it looks maybe like a brush tool setting (maybe spatter?). 
Can someone tell me if there is a relatively **simple** way of doing this on Photoshop CS6, as I am a beginner?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like either a white sack or fabric texture/brush placed on the shapes. You can find a good fabric or sack texture around on the internet and merge it in your project using blending modes. Also you can use some dissolved brush to erase some of the texture to give it that uneven edge look. It should look extremely (similar if the right texture is found) to the photo you supplied.

An example texture so you can understand more clearly (taken from *images.naldzgraphics.net* )
[image]